# How to add cluster to my navigation menu in webspere

Tags: websphere

Hi I want to include cluster option in IBM 8.5 where it is installed on Linux how to add this package through the terminal where in my server menu I have only server types

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough, but here are my assumptions:

- you are using WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.x
- you want to have cluster options in the Web Administrative console (accessed via /ibm/console)

You currently have standalone single server profile, this profile doesnt have cluster management capabilities. You have to create different profile - deployment manager - either via graphical UI - https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-nd/8.5.5?topic=mpugui-creating-management-profiles-deployment-managers or via `manageprofiles.sh` commandline tool - https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-nd/8.5.5?topic=mpnzos-manageprofiles-command-1

To create cluster you will need at least one additional profile (appserver or custom) and federate it to the deployment manager.

Here are various installation secenarios (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-nd/8.5.5?topic=installation-planning-install-websphere-application-server)

The simplest clustering scenario would be [Scenario 7: Single-machine installation of a cell of application servers and a web server](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-nd/8.5.5?topic=installation-planning-install-websphere-application-server#tins_scenario3__sc7)